# Should there be a preposition between "at a loss" and the following question word?

Tags: prepositions

Examples: 
I am at a loss who to blame.
OR 
I am at a loss of who to blame.
OR 
I am at a loss on who to blame.

Comment: Like both answers, I prefer *at a loss* **as to** *what to do*, but apparently it's [far more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+a+loss+to%2Cat+a+loss+as+to&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to simply omit those extra two words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than [], [of] and [on], I think it should be [as to]:

> I am at a loss **as to** who to blame.

A clearer way might be to say:

> I am at a loss **to know** who to blame.

Answer (score 1):

I think to be absolutely correct there should be a preposition, but common usage seems to indicate you can get away without one.

I would tend to say "I am at a loss as to who to blame"

Comment: The *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* gives "at a loss to do sth", which would make "I'm at a loss who to blame" correct, and not only a "get away" thing, wouldn't it ? A google search on "I am at a loss who to" gives lots of hits back. Or could there be a difference between British and American usage?

Answer (score -2):

simple.  at a loss as to WHOM to blame  No preposition needed.
Ken T. Baxendale prize for English 1955

Comment: I'm curious: what part of speech do you think the "to" in "as to" is, if it's not a preposition?